Can't Scroll Item in ExpandablePageView Flutter
Recently, I created an interface using ExpandablePageView (horizontal) combine with Dialog, but the problem is that the view inside ExpandablePageView has a very long height and I wrapped it with SingleScrollView, but I still can't scroll. Is there any property from ExpandablePageView that prevents it? Please let me know, if u guys have any solution for this. Thank u all.

I find the solution that just only add SingleScrollView into Dialog and u can be able scroll the items in ExpandablePageView. That's it
